# Rust. Confusion around using functions from impl in global scope

Tags: rust, types, rc

I am doing examples from the Rust book but I dont understand this one.
How can *a.tail()* use *tail()*, when *tail()* is a function in the implementation of *List* and *a* is of *Rc* type?

```
use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(i32, RefCell<Rc<List>>),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    fn tail(&self) -> Option<&RefCell<Rc<List>>> {
        match self {
            Cons(_, item) => Some(item),
            Nil => None,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(Cons(5, RefCell::new(Rc::new(Nil))));

    println!("a initial rc count = {}", Rc::strong_count(&a));
    println!("a next item = {:?}", a.tail());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Rc is a smart pointer that does `Deref coercion`. That's explained in chapter 15.2 in the book.

Answer (score 3):

`Rc` implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html). That means you can do `&*rc` and get back `&T`, like if it was a reference.

When you call a method, the compiler automatically inserts `&`s and `*`s as necessary. This is called autoref or autoderef. See [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

That's due to automatic dereferencing, or [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) coercion. [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) is a Reference-counted smart pointer and it implements the `Deref` interface, which basically allows you to directly call methods on the value the `Rc` points to (in your case, the `List` enum).

See [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) for more.